# Update JSON objects with Python script for AWS

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

I have a bunch of JSON objects that I need to update in order to use the CLI for AWS. 
Here is an example of the JSON format. I will need to update lbtest, lbtest-cookie-pol and 80 with different values.

```
{
    "LoadBalancerName": "lbtest", 
    "PolicyName": "lbtest-cookie-pol", 
    "CookieExpirationPeriod":80 
}
```

In some cases, there will be multiple values here for each Load Balancer Name.
The output will need to look like this:

```
{
    "LoadBalancerName": "lbtest", 
    "PolicyName": "lbtest-cookie-pol", 
    "CookieExpirationPeriod":80 
}
{
    "LoadBalancerName": "lbtest", 
    "PolicyName": "lbtest-cookie-pol2", 
    "CookieExpirationPeriod":8080. 
}
```

Suppose I had a CSV file with all these entries, what kind of python script can I write to loop through these and print out my JSON output? The part where I am having issues is the printing of the nested JSON object. `print` doesn't seem to like multiple lines or the curly braces that I have. Newbie here so I would appreciate any kind of solution.

Comment: Maybe use json.dumps per https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

Comment: with ctrl+f 'pretty printing'

Answer (score 0):

you can use json.dumps method and it's options mentioned in [documentations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):
for example with using indent option you get this on python 2.7 :

```
>>> dictionary = {
    "LoadBalancerName": "lbtest", 
    "PolicyName": "lbtest-cookie-pol", 
    "CookieExpirationPeriod":80 } #a dictionary object made from csv
>>> print dictionary
{'PolicyName': 'lbtest-cookie-pol', 'CookieExpirationPeriod': 80, 'LoadBalancerName': 'lbtest'}
>>> import json
>>> jobj = json.dumps(dictionary,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
>>> print jobj
{
    "PolicyName": "lbtest-cookie-pol",
    "CookieExpirationPeriod": 80,
    "LoadBalancerName": "lbtest"
}
>>> f = open(r'jtest.txt','w') #save our json object to file
>>> json.dump(dictionary,fp,indent =4 , seperators = (',',': '))
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open(r'jtest.txt!','r') #read our object from file
>>> test = json.load(f)
>>> test
{u'PolicyName': u'lbtest-cookie-pol', u'CookieExpirationPeriod': 80, u'LoadBalancerName': u'lbtest'}
>>> dict(test)
{u'PolicyName': u'lbtest-cookie-pol', u'CookieExpirationPeriod': 80, u'LoadBalancerName': u'lbtest'}
```

here is how our file looks like: 
[jtest.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaehY.png)

Comment: Is there any way to retain the json formatting after the json.dumps is printed out?  The input needs to remain the same.

Comment: @Bleubox111 : i edited the code , and added txt file picture to see ! is that ok ?